# How to fix text change listener error when I implement it?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm having some problems with text change listener in Android Studio.I'm using Fragment, and when I run this, nothing shows at the Logcat. I'm sure I typed the text-edit at the XML file. I have also checked the id and no error has come up.

Please let me know why nothing pops up in Logcat.

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
    private int mPage;
    private EditText fiftythinput;
    private TextView fiftythres;
    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Log.v("tag_t","2");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Log.v("tag_t","3");

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            Log.v("tag_t","1");

        }
    };

    public static FirstFragment newInstance(int page){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        FirstFragment blankFragment = new FirstFragment();
        blankFragment.setArguments(args);
        return blankFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        fiftythinput = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fiftyinput);


        fiftythres = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fiftyres);

        fiftythinput.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

________Add XML________

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fiftyth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="50000원"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fiftythinput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="수량"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fiftythres"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="- \"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you please also post your XML code?

Comment: I Added XML. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Great, I think  I found your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is that your XML code has the edit text labeled as `fiftythres`. In your code, you have it as:

```
fiftythinput = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fiftyinput);
```

What you need to do is this:

```
fiftythinput = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fiftythinput);
```

Hope it helps! If it doesn't, inform me.

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo error as you notice me. The reason that not came up error is there are 'fiftythinput' and 'fiftyinput'. I should check that first... Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too. Glad to help you!